# An algorithm to tell if two cut systems are handle slide equivalent?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, computational-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a genus $g$ closed orientable surface and let $\alpha = \{ \alpha_1,...,\alpha_g\}$ and $\beta = \{ \beta_1 ,..., \beta_g \}$ be two cut systems (i.e. nonintersecting homologically linearly independent sets of $g$ curves) on $\Sigma$.  Is there an algorithm to tell if $\alpha$ is handleslide equivalent to $\beta$?  Or said another way, is there an algorithm to tell if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ describe the same handlebody attached to $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, here is a sketch of one such proof.  Let $V = V_\alpha$ be the genus $g$ handlebody determined by $\alpha$.  The curves $\beta$ now give conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(V)$.  Any one of the $\beta_i$ bounds a disk if and only if its class is trivial.  (Strictly speaking, this requires the disk theorem, but there is a easy proof when the ambient three-manifold is a handlebody.) If all of the $\beta_i$ bound disks in $V$, then an innermost disk argument proves that the $\beta_i$ bound disjointly.  Now an outermost bigon argument gives the desired sequence of handleslides from $\beta$ to $\alpha$.

There are also indirect proofs.  See Theorem 1.4 of a paper of [Carvalho and Oertel](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510610) or Lemma 2.2 of a paper of [Casson and Long](https://eudml.org/doc/143256).